# How add dsPIC33EP128GP502 in Proteus?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, proteus

I use proteus to debug the operation of the PICs.

Now I am going to use a dsPIC33EP128GP502 and in Proteus libraries it does not appear.

I have searched if there is any library of this type of PIC but I have not found anything.

Does anyone know how I can add these dsPIC to proteus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dsPIC is not supporterd by Proteus. Here is a [list](https://www.labcenter.com/documents/?314) of the sopported dsPICs.
Maybe switch to a supportrd controller for your simulation and then switch back to the real one. You could not add a controller on your one.